# How to use the Custon Dataset in Pytorch for Non-Image Data

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, dataset

I am training a spiking neural network consisting of one input neuron and one output (LIF) neuron. I use the custom dataset class from Pytorch which is shown below.

I wish to train this 1 output neuron to spike at a exact frequency regardless of the input frequency, which works very well. I now wish to use more than 1 input to the network and have ran into an issue with this custom dataset class. Note, the input is not an image, just a raw frequency integer which gets encoded into a rate-based spiketrain (0's and 1's).

I specify some setup parameters like this:

```
num_steps = 1000

num_inputs = 1
input_freq = 100
num_outputs = 1
output_freq = 45
```

Now to set the frequency of say 2 inputs, I tried to do so like shown below:

```
num_inputs = 2
input_freq = [100, 50]
```

I think this is the format that the data needs to be in for 2 inputs (with input 0 spike value for each timestep on the left column and input 2 on the right). I have developed an encoder function to convert the 100Hz and 50Hz in to the spiketrains.

[image: 2 input tensor format]

But now the custom dataset interprets this as 2 separate data samples I believe. How can this be achieved? I would like to keep using the custom dataset class. It is overkill for what I am currently doing, but I will be scaling things up with a bigger dataset.

Has anyone did this before?

```
    class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):

            self.data_info = [input_freq]
            self.label_info = [0]

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        single_data = self.data_info[index]
        single_label = self.label_info[index]

        return torch.tensor(single_data), torch.tensor(single_label)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_info)


d = CustomDataset()

train_loader = DataLoader(d, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, drop_last=False)
test_loader = DataLoader(d, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, drop_last=False)

train_batch = iter(train_loader)
test_batch = iter(test_loader)

# for data, targets in train_batch:
#     print("target:", targets)
#     print("data:", data)
#     print("")

# for data, targets in test_batch:
#     print("target:", targets)
#     print("data:", data)
#     print("")

device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
```